# Get all selected values of multiple drop downs and append them into a string variable

Tags: javascript, select

From the following three drop downs in a jsp page,I want append all the selected values and store in a single string variable.

```
<Select id="one" >
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select><br>

<Select id="two" >
    <option value="x">x</option>
    <option value="y">y</option>
    <option value="z">z</option>
</select><br>

<Select id="three" >
    <option value="m">m</option>
    <option value="l">l</option>
    <option value="n">n</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: all the selected options regardless of the <select> tag ?

Comment: if user selects option "a" from first drop down and "z" from second dropdown and "l" from thrid drop down,those three values should be append and stored in variable,hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "";
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
  str += $( this ).val() + " ";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/9hNmY/

```
var myString = "";
$('select').change(function(){
    myString = $('#one').val() + $('#two').val() + $('#three').val();

    $('div').text(myString);
});
```